# if statement javascript on select tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to writing JavaScript
I want to write something like this but I cant access the opt group in my JavaScript …

if (select-country value == an option in optgroup(africa) ){

countryGrade=50

}

else if(select-country value == an option in optgroup(north america) ){

countryGrade=20

}

else if(select-country value == an option in optgroup(south america) ){

countryGrade=30

}

it is a form so when the form is submitted it will go over the conditions

what i to do is assign points to the country grade that is why im using if statement

```js
var scholarshipGrade=document.getElementById("scholar_grade")
var form=document.getElementById("form")
var age=document.getElementById("age")
var fname=document.getElementById("fname")
var mname=document.getElementById("mname")
var lname=document.getElementById("name")
var ageGrade=0
var countryGrade=0
var subjectGrade=0;
scholarshipGrade=ageGrade+countryGrade+subjectGrade
form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    if(age.value >=18 && age.value <=24){
        ageGrade= 100
    }
    else if(age.value >=25 && age.value <=30){
        ageGrade=80
    }
    else if(age.value >=31 && age.value <=35){
        ageGrade=50
    }
    else if(age.value >=36 && age.value <=40){
        ageGrade=30
    }
    else if(age.value >=41){
        ageGrade=10
    }
    
    
})
```

```css
body{    
    background-color:gray;  
  }  
    
  h1{
      text-align: center;
  }
  p{
      text-align: center;
  }
  input[type=text], select, textarea, input[type=email]{  
    width: 100%;  
    padding: 15px;  
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;  
    display: inline-block; 
    border: none;  
    background: #f1f1f1;  
  }
```

```html
<Html>  
    <head> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>  
    Scholarship Project 
    </title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <h1>Apply For Scholarship</h1>
        <div><p>You can apply for a scholarship here, check if you qualify after filling the following fields,after all fields are filled submit the form</p></div>
    <form id="form" name="form">  
      
    <label> Firstname </label>         
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" /> <br> <br>  
    <label> Middlename: </label>     
    <input type="text" name="middlename" id="mname"/> <br> <br>  
    <label> Lastname: </label>         
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"/> <br> <br>  
    <br>  
    <label>   
    Gender :  
    </label> 
    <input type="radio" name="male"/> Male  
    <input type="radio" name="female"/> Female 
    <br>  
    <br>  
    <label>Enter your age: </label>  
    <input type="number" id= "age" name="num" min="18" max="60"><br> <br>
      
    <label>   
    Phone :  
    </label>  
    <input type="text" name="phone" /> <br> <br>  
    Address  
    <br>  
    <textarea cols="80" rows="5" value="address">  
    </textarea>  
    <br> <br>  
    Email:  
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/> <br>    
    <br> <br>  
    <label for="country">select your country</label> <br>

    <select id="select-country" name="country" >
        <option value="" selected="">Select country</option>
        <optgroup label="Africa" id="africa" >
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AO">Angola</option>
            <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
            <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
            <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
            <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
            <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
            <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
            <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
            <option value="TD">Chad</option>
            <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
            <option value="CG">Congo</option>
            <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
            <option value="DJ">Dijibouti</option>
            <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
            <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
            <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
            <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
            <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
            <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
            <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
            <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
            <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
            <option value="CI">Cote d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)</option>
            <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
            <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
            <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
            <option value="LY">Libya</option>
            <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
            <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
            <option value="ML">Mali</option>
            <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
            <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
            <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
            <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
            <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
            <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
            <option value="NE">Niger</option>
            <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
            <option value="RE">Reunion</option>
            <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
            <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
            <option value="SH">Saint Helena</option>
            <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
            <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
            <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
            <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
            <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
            <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
            <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
            <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
            <option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
            <option value="TG">Togo</option>
            <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
            <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
            <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
            <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup data-points='20' label="North America" class="namerica">
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
            <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
            <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
            <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
            <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option>
            <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
            <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
            <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
            <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
            <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
            <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
            <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
            <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
            <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
            <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
            <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
            <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
            <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
            <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
            <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
            <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
            <option value="PA">Panama</option>
            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
            <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
            <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
            <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
            <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
            <option value="VI">US Virgin Islands</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup data-points='30' label="South America" class="samerica">
            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
            <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
            <option value="CL">Chile</option>
            <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
            <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
            <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
            <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
            <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
            <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="PE">Peru</option>
            <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
            <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
            <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup data-points='40' label="Asia" class="asia">
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
            <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
            <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
            <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="CN">China</option>
            <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
            <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
            <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
            <option value="IN">India</option>
            <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="IR">Iran</option>
            <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
            <option value="IL">Israel</option>
            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
            <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
            <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
            <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
            <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
            <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
            <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
            <option value="LA">Lao</option>
            <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
            <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="MM">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
            <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
            <option value="OM">Oman</option>
            <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
            <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
            <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
            <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
            <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="SY">Syria</option>
            <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
            <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
            <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
            <option value="TP">East Timor</option>
            <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
            <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
            <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
            <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup data-points='10' label="Rest Of The World" class="rotws">
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
            <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
            <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
            <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="HR">Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
            <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
            <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
            <option value="GR">Greece</option>
            <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
            <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
            <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
            <option value="MT">Malta</option>
            <option value="MD">Moldova</option>
            <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
            <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="PL">Poland</option>
            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
            <option value="RO">Romania</option>
            <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
            <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
            <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
            <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
            <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
            <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
            <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
            <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
            <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
            <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
            <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
            <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
            <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
            <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
            <option value="PF">French Polynesia (Tahiti)</option>
            <option value="GU">Guam</option>
            <option value="KB">Kiribati</option>
            <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
            <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
            <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
            <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="NU">Niue</option>
            <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
            <option value="PW">Palau</option>
            <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
            <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
            <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
            <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
            <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
            <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
            <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
            <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
            <option valud="WF">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select><br><br>
    <label for="subjects"></label>
    <select  name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <select name ="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
        <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
        <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
    <button  type="submit">submit</button>

    </form>  
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p id="scholar_grade"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: You can look at here http://jsfiddle.net/pyG2v/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the associated optgroup and points value for a given country, you need to access the option selected

```
let opt = countrySelect.options[countrySelect.selectedIndex]
  let optgrp = opt.closest('optgroup');
  let continent = optgrp.label
  let points = optgrp.dataset.points
  let country = countrySelect.value
  let countryname = opt.innerText
  console.log(`You selected the country ${countryname} (value ${country}) that is in ${continent} for ${points} points`);
```

```js
 

var scholarshipGrade = document.getElementById("scholar_grade")
var form = document.getElementById("form")
var age = document.getElementById("age")
var fname = document.getElementById("fname")
var mname = document.getElementById("mname")
var lname = document.getElementById("name")
let countrySelect = document.querySelector('#select-country')
var ageGrade = 0
var countryGrade = 0
var subjectGrade = 0;
scholarshipGrade = ageGrade + countryGrade + subjectGrade
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  // country stuff
  
  let opt = countrySelect.options[countrySelect.selectedIndex]
  let optgrp = opt.closest('optgroup');
  let continent = optgrp.label
  let points = optgrp.dataset.points
  let country = countrySelect.value
  let countryname = opt.innerText
  console.log(`You selected the country ${countryname} (value ${country}) that is in ${continent} for ${points} points`);
  
  // age stuff
  if (age.value >= 18 && age.value <= 24) {
    ageGrade = 100
  } else if (age.value >= 25 && age.value <= 30) {
    ageGrade = 80
  } else if (age.value >= 31 && age.value <= 35) {
    ageGrade = 50
  } else if (age.value >= 36 && age.value <= 40) {
    ageGrade = 30
  } else if (age.value >= 41) {
    ageGrade = 10
  }


})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text],
select,
textarea,
input[type=email] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Apply For Scholarship</h1>
<div>
  <p>You can apply for a scholarship here, check if you qualify after filling the following fields,after all fields are filled submit the form</p>
</div>
<form id="form" name="form">

  <label> Firstname </label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" /> <br> <br>
  <label> Middlename: </label>
  <input type="text" name="middlename" id="mname" /> <br> <br>
  <label> Lastname: </label>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname" /> <br> <br>
  <br>
  <label>   
    Gender :  
    </label>
  <input type="radio" name="male" /> Male
  <input type="radio" name="female" /> Female
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Enter your age: </label>
  <input type="number" id="age" name="num" min="18" max="60"><br> <br>

  <label>   
    Phone :  
    </label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" /> <br> <br> Address
  <br>
  <textarea cols="80" rows="5" value="address">  
    </textarea>
  <br> <br> Email:
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" /> <br>
  <br> <br>
  <label for="country">select your country</label> <br>

  <select id="select-country" name="country">
    <option value="" selected="">Select country</option>
    <optgroup data-points='30' label="Africa" id="africa">
      <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
      <option value="AO">Angola</option>
      <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
      <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
      <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
      <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
      <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
      <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
      <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
      <option value="TD">Chad</option>
      <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
      <option value="CG">Congo</option>
      <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
      <option value="DJ">Dijibouti</option>
      <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
      <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
      <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
      <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
      <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
      <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
      <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
      <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
      <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
      <option value="CI">Cote d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)</option>
      <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
      <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
      <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
      <option value="LY">Libya</option>
      <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
      <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
      <option value="ML">Mali</option>
      <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
      <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
      <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
      <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
      <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
      <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
      <option value="NE">Niger</option>
      <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
      <option value="RE">Reunion</option>
      <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
      <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
      <option value="SH">Saint Helena</option>
      <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
      <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
      <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
      <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
      <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
      <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
      <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
      <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
      <option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
      <option value="TG">Togo</option>
      <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
      <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
      <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
      <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
      <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-points='20' label="North America" class="namerica">
      <option value="US">United States</option>
      <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
      <option value="CA">Canada</option>
      <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
      <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
      <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
      <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
      <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
      <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
      <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
      <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
      <option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option>
      <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
      <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
      <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
      <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
      <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
      <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
      <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
      <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
      <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
      <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
      <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
      <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
      <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
      <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
      <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
      <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
      <option value="PA">Panama</option>
      <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
      <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
      <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
      <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
      <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
      <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
      <option value="VI">US Virgin Islands</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-points='30' label="South America" class="samerica">
      <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
      <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
      <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
      <option value="CL">Chile</option>
      <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
      <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
      <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
      <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
      <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
      <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
      <option value="PE">Peru</option>
      <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
      <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
      <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-points='40' label="Asia" class="asia">
      <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
      <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
      <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
      <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
      <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
      <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
      <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
      <option value="CN">China</option>
      <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
      <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
      <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
      <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
      <option value="IN">India</option>
      <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
      <option value="IR">Iran</option>
      <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
      <option value="IL">Israel</option>
      <option value="JP">Japan</option>
      <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
      <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
      <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
      <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
      <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
      <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
      <option value="LA">Lao</option>
      <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
      <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
      <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
      <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
      <option value="MM">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
      <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
      <option value="OM">Oman</option>
      <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
      <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
      <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
      <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
      <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
      <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
      <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
      <option value="SY">Syria</option>
      <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
      <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
      <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
      <option value="TP">East Timor</option>
      <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
      <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
      <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
      <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
      <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup data-points='10' label="Rest Of The World" class="rotws">
      <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
      <option value="AL">Albania</option>
      <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
      <option value="AT">Austria</option>
      <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
      <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
      <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
      <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="HR">Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
      <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
      <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
      <option value="FR">France</option>
      <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
      <option value="DE">Germany</option>
      <option value="GR">Greece</option>
      <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
      <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
      <option value="IT">Italy</option>
      <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
      <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
      <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
      <option value="MT">Malta</option>
      <option value="MD">Moldova</option>
      <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
      <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
      <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="PL">Poland</option>
      <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
      <option value="RO">Romania</option>
      <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
      <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
      <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
      <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
      <option value="ES">Spain</option>
      <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
      <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
      <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
      <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
      <option value="FI">Finland</option>
      <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
      <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
      <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
      <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
      <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
      <option value="NO">Norway</option>
      <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
      <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
      <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
      <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
      <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
      <option value="AU">Australia</option>
      <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
      <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
      <option value="PF">French Polynesia (Tahiti)</option>
      <option value="GU">Guam</option>
      <option value="KB">Kiribati</option>
      <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
      <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
      <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
      <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
      <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
      <option value="NU">Niue</option>
      <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
      <option value="PW">Palau</option>
      <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
      <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
      <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
      <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
      <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
      <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
      <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
      <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
      <option valud="WF">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select><br><br>
  <label for="subjects"></label>
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <select name="subjects" id="subjects" filter="filter-std">
    <option value="" selected="">Select subjects</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="score" id="score">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
<div>
  <p></p>
  <p id="scholar_grade"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: see what im trying to do here